# c string pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm starting to learn C and I'm a little bit confuse with c string pointer.

```
int argc = 0;
const char *str[] = { "hello" , NULL, NULL };
str[argc++] = "nice!";
str[argc++] = "abc";
str[argc++] = "def"
send_args(argc, str); 
//the prototype/header : int send_args(int argc, const char **args);
```

because send_args function doesn't modify the value of passed str, are those operation valid?
because I don't want to do something like :

```
int i, argc = 0;
char *str[3];
str[argc++] = strdup("nice!");
str[argc++] = strdup("abc");
str[argc++] = strduo("def)"
send_args(argc, str);
for (i = 0; i< argc; i++)
    if (str[i]) { free(str[i]); str[i]=NULL; }
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: What do you intend to do with `send_args()`? I am not sure, if your array is correctly initialized and it can hold all the values. I think the compiler might optimize the last two `NULL` away and you might write to unreferenced memory.

Comment: No, the compiler cannot optimize array elements away for exactly this reason: the size of the array is a relevant part of the program's data.

Answer (score 4):

I see nothing wrong with the first example.

Comment: I think the OP calls `free` because he calls `strdup`, which does calls `malloc`.

Comment: strdup does an implicit malloc.

Comment: free because I do strdup, which is allocate memory to char pointer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's alright. The string literals are likely placed in the initialized data section (details are implementation defined) and there is no need (in fact, not even a possibility) to free literals. 
The type of `str` is compatible with the one required by `send_args`, so all is fine.

Note that as written, `str[]` is initialized with three elements and thus cannot hold four or more pointers. You could achieve the same effect with a declaration and initialization like

```
const char *str[3];
str[0] = "nice!";
str[1] = "abc";
str[2] = "def"
send_args(3, str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are perfectly valid. You need to be concerned about `argc` though because you are incrementing it one more than needed. It would not cause any "undesirable effects" as far as you are handling it correctly. You can check your code's example [here](http://codepad.org/OPp7Lfig)

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about automatic storage duration, your `str` array won't be destroyed until execution reaches the end of the block it was created within.

```
const char **fubar(void)
{
    int argc = 0;
    const char *str[] = { "hello" , NULL, NULL }; /* str is created here */
    str[argc++] = "nice!";
    str[argc++] = "abc";
    str[argc++] = "def"
    send_args(argc, str); /* the lifetime of str is still valid here */
    return str; /* ... but str gets destroyed after this "return" statement */
}

int main(void) {
  const char **fubared = fubar();
  /* str has already been destroyed, and fubar's return value has been rendered garbage */
  /* so using fubared would be a bad idea. */
  return 0;
}
```

`return` causes str to be destroyed, because execution has surpassed the end of the block it was created within, and the pointer being returned would point to garbage.

Answer (score -1):

In this case they are valid, because the strings are stored statically at compile time and cannot be freed. Their pointer addresses also do not depend on the function you are in.

But if you would use a local char array for `"nice!"`, it would not be valid, because the send_args cannot read local variables of other functions.